# not getting any results!! is there an error with the pdo code?

Tags: php

The code is not giving any result can you help me ?

```
$f_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$l_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$e_mail = $_POST['email']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO
            informations(first name, last name,email ,email)
        VALUES($f_name,$l_name,$e_mail)";

 /*$result = pdo::query($sql);
if(!$result)*/
    $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!$result)
{
    //something went wrong, display the error
    echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
    //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
}
else
{
    echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> and start posting! :-)';
}
```

Comment: You cannot "fetch" from an UPDATE. Only a SELECT returns rows. (Also, please see a tutorial for how to *correctly* use PDO.)

Answer (score 1):

You currently aren't using PDO propertly, you're fetching results with an insert query, and you aren't making the most of parameter binding.

Try this:

```
// make sure $db is initialized as a new PDO object
// use :param placeholders for binding
$sql = "INSERT INTO informations(first name, last name, email) VALUES(:first, :last, :email)";

// prepare query
$query = $db->prepare($sql);

// set up parameter binding replacements    
$binding = array(
    ':first' => $f_name,
    ':last' => $l_name,
    ':email' => $e_mail // strange variable name splitting...
);

// execute the query (returns boolean true or false)
$query_results = $query->execute($binding);

// process result message
if($query_results) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong! Error: ' . $query->errorInfo();
}
```

**For reference:**

- [PDO::execute() manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- [PDO introduction tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [Another PDO tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/214733-introduction-to-pdo/)